# Why won't my php script return results?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Please check out this mock up of a search on my site:

LINK EXPIRED

The search doesn't return any results and no error messages are shown, why is this?

I have taken out my person information ie. host/username/password

```
HTML:
  <h2>Search</h2> 
  <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
  Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
  <Select NAME="field">
  <Option VALUE="fname">First Name</option>
  <Option VALUE="lname">Last Name</option>
  <Option VALUE="info">Profile</option>
  </Select>
  <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
  </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
//This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
if ($searching =="yes") 
{ 
echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
if ($find == "") 
{ 
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
exit; 
} 

// Otherwise we connect to our Database 
mysql_connect("MYHOST", "MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("MYDATABSENAME") or die(mysql_error()); 

// We preform a bit of filtering 
$find = strtoupper($find); 
$find = strip_tags($find); 
$find = trim ($find); 

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

//And we display the results 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
echo $result['fname']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['lname']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo $result['info']; 
echo "<br>"; 
echo "<br>"; 
} 

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives
them a little    message explaining that 
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
if ($anymatches == 0) 
{ 
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
} 

//And we remind them what they searched for 
echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
} 
?>
```

Thanks!

Jmames

Comment: There is more than one reason

Comment: There is not enough error checking, the code is badly structured, it relies on register_globals, you've not provided important relevant information like whether the system is configured to report / log errors, nor if the script completes without aborting...there's probably more issues with the code than just this though.

Answer (score 6):

You are assuming the server is using [register_globals](http://php.net/register_globals), which is a terrible terrible thing. You should do something like `if ($_POST['searching'] =="yes")` instead. This is probaly also why nothing happens.

The [docs](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) says

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Your code is also extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wiki%20sql%20injection&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=pCfWTrL5DYrLswa50qHRDg&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&sig2=U4O7ejRxB4L2CwzDJlpU5g), which you can fix with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Your query should look like this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper(".mysql_real_escape_string($field).") LIKE'%".mysql_real_escape_string($find)."%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write:

```
$searching = $_POST['searching'];
```

Before:

```
if ($searching =="yes")
```

?